# Is there a way to extract the file path of audio files in the Media Library?

Tags: ios, audio

I'm working on a music player for iOS, and I was wondering if there was a way to extract the file path of audio files inside the iPod/Media Library on iOS. I've read multiple articles, and it seems you can only extract an URL which can be only used with the AV framework player.

So can you extract the file name of audio files in the Media Library and play these files using an external audio library?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you get any further on this?